# Angular - How to exclude timezone hours from formatted date in a date pipe?

Tags: angular, date, typescript, date-fns

I'm trying to format a date but I keep coming across the issue that the timezone is added to the time whenever I format it. When calling `.toUTCString()` it works but that will give me a format I don't want. So I want to call `.toUTCString()` and then format the date. But then the timezone is back.

I'm using the `date-fns` framework but maybe this can be achieved with just javascript date functions?

How can I format a date and avoid adding extra hours to the date since the GMT is +2? For `10:00` I get `12:00` for example.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'exactDate'
})

export class ExactDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, args: string) {

    const parsedDate: string = datefns.format(new Date(value).toUTCString(), args);

    return parsedDate;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) is very clear that

> It always returns a date in the local timezone, no matter what you passed: a timestamp, a string or a date object.

If I understand your question correctly you do not want that behavior.  Instead, try using the **options** parameter provided by the Date.toLocaleString function, for example

```
var date = new Date(),
  options = {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    timeZoneName: 'short'
  },
  str = date.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
  // str format like "5/31/2017, 1:55:21 PM GMT"
```

You have total control over the formatting - here's the [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Comment: What if I want a format of `2017-05-05 14:00` for example?

Comment: I assumed you're using date-fns to support locale-specific formatting.  If that's not the case, then simply use the Date.getUTC* functions and assemble the resulting string as needed.

Comment: Can you share a complete example? I'm stuck on this. I need to be able to pass the format as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm` for example. I don't care how the date is formatted as long as you can pass a format you want.

Comment: Managed to solve it by using `subHours` of the `date-fns` lib.